# How can I draw this kind of Jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart, dynamic-reports, candlestick-chart

I am using Dynamicreports4.1.1, whose chart based on Jfreechart.

I want to draw chart like image below:
[image]

It somewhat like **Candlestickchart** or **stackedchart** or **layeredchart**.

I choose the **stackedchart** to customize, it like this:
[image]

The code:

```
public class StackedBarChartReportTest {

public StackedBarChartReportTest() {
    build();
}

private void build() {
    FontBuilder boldFont = stl.fontArialBold().setFontSize(12);

    TextColumnBuilder<String> itemColumn = col.column("Item", "item", type.stringType());
    TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> bestColumn = col.column("Best", "best", type.bigDecimalType());
    TextColumnBuilder<BigDecimal> worstColumn = col.column("Worst", "worst", type.bigDecimalType());
    try {
        report()
            .setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate)
            .columns(itemColumn, bestColumn, worstColumn)
            .title(Templates.createTitleComponent("StackedBarChart"))
            .summary(
                cht.stackedBarChart()
                    .customizers(new ChartCustomizer())
                    .setTitle("Stacked bar chart")
                    .setTitleFont(boldFont)
                    .setCategory(itemColumn)
                    .setShowValues(true)
                    .series(
                        cht.serie(bestColumn), cht.serie(worstColumn))
                    .setCategoryAxisFormat(
                        cht.axisFormat().setLabel("Item")))
            .pageFooter(Templates.footerComponent)
            .setDataSource(createDataSource())
            .show();
    } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class ChartCustomizer implements DRIChartCustomizer, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, ReportParameters reportParameters) {
        BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
        // here customize,but have no idea...

    }
}
private JRDataSource createDataSource() {
    DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("item", "best", "worst");
    dataSource.add("1Y", new BigDecimal(-10), new BigDecimal(-14.5));
    dataSource.add("2Y", new BigDecimal(10), new BigDecimal(4));
    dataSource.add("3Y", new BigDecimal(12), new BigDecimal(-2));
    return dataSource;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new StackedBarChartReportTest();
}
```

Have no idea how to start or Is there a chart like this?

Comment: I'd look among the _Bar Charts_ in the [tag:jfreechart] demo/gallery of sample charts and try a custom label generator; please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your chosen approach..

Comment: Sorry not make clearly, I even can't draw that type of chart, not just the label..., I edited it

Comment: Sorry, I don't know `DRIChartCustomizer`. Also consider a `MinMaxCategoryRenderer` with a custom stroke.